# How can I bind from one form to 2 different tables without getting this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a two part form that requests some input from the user and then adds default values to other fields before posting to two different tables then forwarding them onto the another form.  I'm using ASP.net 4.5.1 MVC5 and Code First Entity Framework.  The error I see is "not all code paths return a value."  This is my first EF .net project and I can use help.  Thank you.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CampaignType,Location,CampaignTitle,ShortIntro,Amount,StartDate,EndDate")] Campaign campaign)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool Featured = false;
            string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            bool AcceptTerms = true;
            bool Active = true;
            DateTime DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            int Status = 2;
            db.Campaigns.Add(campaign);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
            return View();
    }

     public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CampaignID,Cost,Description,DeliveryDate,DeliveryDesc,MaxQuantity")] Service service)
            {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                int Status = 2;
                db.Services.Add(service);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("CampaignCreatorProfile", "Create");
            }

        return View();
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Create` method does not have a return value for the if.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CampaignType,Location,CampaignTitle,ShortIntro,Amount,StartDate,EndDate")] Campaign campaign) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        bool Featured = false;
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        bool AcceptTerms = true;
        bool Active = true;
        DateTime DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        int Status = 2;
        db.Campaigns.Add(campaign);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else {
        // Do something to handle when the Model is not valid.
    }

    // Move your return statement outside the scope of the else.
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I need to update both tables.   I'm getting an ambiguous error now because there are two create actions.

Comment: This is the resolution to the problem that you presented, which is different than the title of your question. Please make a new question with further details of your data mappings.